# Python and temporary files when moved to temp path they are not considered files anymore

Tags: python, temporary-files

We've created a temporary directory within a python function to move files into for processing:

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as workdir:

```
temp_dir = Path(workdir)
print(temp_dir)

sub_odk_extract = urllib.request.urlretrieve(sub_odk_url, 'sub_odk.xlsx')
sub_odk = sub_odk_extract[0]
sub_odk_path = temp_dir / sub_odk
print('test: ', sub_odk_path, ' Path', isfile(sub_odk_path.read()))
```

the following `print(temp_dir)` is printing the path as:

> C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3efhg0aw

Also when we check if `sub_odk` is a file that was successfully extracted the returned value is true. Also we were able to test it out of the temporary folder successfully.

However when we move it to the temp folder as:

```
sub_odk_path = temp_dir / sub_odk
```

The sub_odk_path is not considered as a file as the result of the print is:

> test:  C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3efhg0aw\sub_odk.xlsx
> Path False

How can we move any file into a temporary folder and do changes over it before the deletion of the temp folder.

Comment: You didn't tell us what `isfile` is, but if it's `os.path.isfile` the argument should be the path to the file, not the content of the file

Comment: @Matthias isfile() was imported from different module so it's not os.path.isfile()

Comment: @Matthias os.path.isfile() returned false

Comment: And what was the parameter you fed to `os.path.isfile()`? As I said: `sub_odk_path.read()` makes no sense. You need the path to the file, not the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

In that last print function, it's not entirely clear what function you're calling with `isfile()`.  Additionally, you're not passing a file to it, you're passing the return value of `sub_odk_path.read()`, which is most likely not going to be a file.

Since you're using pathlib, you can just use the Path.is_file() method.

```
print('test: ', sub_odk_path, ' Path', sub_odk_path.is_file())
```

Comment: this one also returned False. the file retrieved from url can be read normally. however, I am using http triggers of Azure and we need to work with tmp folders in order to load them there and call them back. this is how I got it.

Comment: is it possible that by the file is being put into your current working directory instead of the temporary directory?  As you're only passing a filename and not a full filepath to urllibs.request.urlretrieve(), it's not clear to me that it would be putting the file into tempdir

Comment: it worked with adding /tmp to the path which will be the temp folder of the azure's deployed function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `os.path.isfile(sub_odk_path)` instead of isfile(...)

Comment: this one returned False also

Comment: this one also returned False. the file retrieved from url can be read normally. however, I am using http triggers of Azure and we need to work with tmp folders in order to load them there and call them back. this is how I got it.